# Substitution in text file **without** regular expressions

Tags: bash, regex, sed, text-editing

I need to substitute some text inside a text file with a replacement. Usually I would do something like

```
sed -i 's/text/replacement/g' path/to/the/file
```

The problem is that both `text` and `replacement` are complex strings containing dashes, slashes, blackslashes, quotes and so on. If I escape all necessary characters inside `text` the thing becomes quickly unreadable. On the other hand I do not need the power of regular expressions: I just need to substitute the text literally.

> Is there a way to do text substitution **without** using regular expressions with some bash command?

It would be rather trivial to write a script that does this, but I figure there should exist something already.

Comment: Necessary to do it through bash? A simplistic solution would be to open in Word and do a `find and replace all`

Comment: @akash Because systems that have `bash` always ship with Microsoft Word? ;) No.. Just kidding. The OP might want to do this on a remote machine or for a batch of files though.

Comment: @slhck :) Well, I guess gedit should have a similar option

Comment: An option would be to *somehow* correctly escape everything before passing it to `sed`, which is probably a futile effort considering all the switches and platform differences.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/a/1368785/500826). tl;dr: use `tr`, `sed` with `y/`. Take a look to [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge).

Comment: Also have this problem and I am puzzled that a software that was written in 1974, nobody ever bothered to implement a simple string replacement. Isn't this a thing you would have even done before implementing regex? I'm speechless.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you don't need the power of regular expressions, don't use it. That is fine.
But, this is not really a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
sed 's|literal_pattern|replacement_string|g'
```

So, if `/` is your problem, use `|` and you don't need to escape the former.

PS: About the comments, also see this Stackoverflow answer on [Escape a string for sed search pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705678/70482).

---

**Update**: If you are fine using **Perl** try it with `\Q` and `\E` like this,

```
 perl -pe 's|\Qliteral_pattern\E|replacement_string|g'
```

<sub>@RedGrittyBrick has also suggested a similar trick with stronger Perl syntax in a comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/422459/substitution-in-text-file-without-regular-expressions#comment484003_422478) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048144/70482)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the difference between / and |

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is useful...  The only difference between `s|||` and `s///` is that the seperator character is different and so that **one** character doesn't need escaping.  You could equally do `s###`.  The real issue here is that the OP doesn't want to have to worry about escaping the contents of `literal_pattern` (which is not literal at all and will be interpreted as a regex).

Comment: This will not avoid the interpretation of other special characters. What if search for `1234.*aaa` with your solution it match much more than the intended `1234\.\*aaa`.

Comment: This answer should *not* be accepted

Comment: This misses the point entirely. The text to be matched could contain any wierdness. In my case it's a random password. You know how those go

Comment: Use `str =~ s/\Q$replace_this\E/$with_this/;` in case of variables

Comment: I agree with Steven Lu, because it is simply wrong. The first character after 's' in "s/aaa/bbb/" is just an arbitrary delimiter and can be anything, as long as it doesn't occur in aaa or bbb. These three give exactly the same result, and 'aaa' will *always* be interpreted as a regular expression by sed: 's/aaa/bbb/', 's|aaa|bbb|', and even 'scaaacbbbc'.  https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Comment: This problem was so annoying that I made a CLI tool to do it: https://github.com/paralin/git-find-replace

Comment: For me Perl solution worked only with `/` separators.

Comment: `perl` with `\Q` `\L` did not help to replace `\\`.

Answer (score 22):

```
export FIND='find this'
export REPLACE='replace with this'
ruby -p -i -e "gsub(ENV['FIND'], ENV['REPLACE'])" path/to/file
```

This is the only 100% safe solution here, because:

- It's a static substition, not a regexp, no need to escape anything (thus, superior to using `sed`)
- It won't break if your string contains `}` char (thus, superior to a submitted Perl solution)
- It won't break with any character, because `ENV['FIND']` is used, not `$FIND`. With `$FIND` or your text inlined in Ruby code, you could hit a syntax error if your string contained an unescaped `'`.

Comment: I had to use `export FIND='find this; export REPLACE='replace with this';` in my bash script so that `ENV['FIND']` and `ENV['replace']` had the expected values. I was replacing some really long encrypted strings in a file. This was just the ticket.

Comment: This is a good answer answer because it's reliable and ruby is ubiquitous. Based on this answer I now use [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/pesterhazy/72f98f600313e1a9ce1036dffb7ca8b1).

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work when FIND contains multiple lines.

Comment: There's nothing that would prevent it from working with multiple lines in FIND. Use double quoted \n.

Comment: you dont need `export`, you can pass variables to subshells in sh by declaring them before the command on the same line; `FIND='find this' REPLACE='replace with this' ruby ....` with no newlines. Especially handy if you were never working with variables in the first place: `FIND=\`echo command\` REPLACE=\`cat replace.txt\` ruby ...`. Use `\\` if you still want newlines in the actual script anyway ;)

Answer (score 14):

The `replace` command will do this.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/replace

Change in place:

```
replace text replacement -- path/to/the/file
```

To stdout:

```
replace text replacement < path/to/the/file
```

Example:

```
$ replace '.*' '[^a-z ]{1,3}' <<EOF
> r1: /.*/g
> r2: /.*/gi
> EOF
r1: /[^a-z ]{1,3}/g
r2: /[^a-z ]{1,3}/gi
```

The `replace` command comes with MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: take into account tht replace is deprecated and may not be disponible in the future

Comment: Why on earth does such  basic command come with a database?

Comment: @masterxilo A better question might be – why does such a basic command not come with modern operating systems? ;-)

Comment: I installed MariaDB, `cp /usr/bin/replace ~/.local/bin` (in $PATH) and then uninstalled it.

Comment: @PabloA Nice idea!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it converting the patterns to their escaped form automatically. Like this:

```
keyword_raw=$'1\n2\n3'
keyword_regexp="$(printf '%s' "$keyword_raw" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s,\n,\\n,g')"
# keyword_regexp is now '1\/2\/3'

replacement_raw=$'2\n3\n4'
replacement_regexp="$(printf '%s' "$replacement_raw" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s,\n,\\n,g')"
# replacement_regexp is now '2\/3\/4'

echo $'a/b/c/1\n2\n3/d/e/f' | sed -e "s/$keyword_regexp/$replacement_regexp/"
# the last command will print 'a/b/c/2\n3\n4/d/e/f'
```

Credits for this solutions goes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Note1: this only works for non-empty keywords. Empty keywords are not accepted by sed (`sed -e 's//replacement/'`).

Note2: unfortunately, I don't know a popular tool that would NOT use regexp-s to solve the problem. You can write such a tool in Rust or C, but it's not there by default.

Comment: This completely misses the OP's point. Obviously you can escape the pattern, but for some patterns this is tedious.

Comment: @icecreamsword did you read my answer below the first line? The script does escaping **automatically**.

Comment: Does not work for me, it prints `a/b/c/1<break>2<break>3/d/e/f`, unless I remove the `$` prefix from strings in variable assignments. Would you mind explaining the script `':a;N;$!ba'`? My understanding was that the second sed expression is unnecessary. Did you really intend to use actual line breaks in the strings?

Comment: Works for me except on bash this emits a bunch of warning to stderr when used on macOS (but still works) such as `sed: 1: ":a;N;$!ba;s,\n,\\n,g": unused label 'a;N;$!ba;s,\n,\\n,g'`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use perl's `\Q` mechanism to "[quote (disable) pattern metacharacters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences)"

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {$text = q{your */text/?goes"here"}} s/\Q$text\E/replacement/g'
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe 's(\Qyour */text/?goes"here")(replacement)' file`

Answer (score 4):

check out my Perl script. it do exactly what you need without implicit or explicit use of regular expression :

https://github.com/Samer-Al-iraqi/Linux-str_replace

```
str_replace Search Replace File # replace in File in place

STDIN | str_replace Search Replace # to STDOUT
```

very handy right? I had to learn Perl to do it. because I really really need it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an enhancement
of [Hashbrown’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/422459/354511#1519414)
(and [wef’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54059656/3960947#54059658)
to a very similar question).

We can remove the issue of the special meaning of various special characters
and strings (`^`, `.`, `[`, `*`, `$`, `\(`, `\)`, `\{`, `\}`, `\+`, `\?`,
`&`, `\1`, …, whatever, and the `/` delimiter)
by *removing the special characters.*
Specifically, we can convert everything to hex;
then we have only `0`-`9` and `a`-`f` to deal with. 
This example demonstrates the principle:

```
$ echo -n '3.14' | xxd
0000000: 332e 3134                                3.14

$ echo -n 'pi'   | xxd
0000000: 7069                                     pi

$ echo '3.14 is a transcendental number.  3614 is an integer.'     | xxd
0000000: 332e 3134 2069 7320 6120 7472 616e 7363  3.14 is a transc
0000010: 656e 6465 6e74 616c 206e 756d 6265 722e  endental number.
0000020: 2020 3336 3134 2069 7320 616e 2069 6e74    3614 is an int
0000030: 6567 6572 2e0a                           eger..

$ echo "3.14 is a transcendental number.  3614 is an integer." | xxd -p |
                                                       sed 's/332e3134/7069/g' | xxd -p -r
pi is a transcendental number.  3614 is an integer.
```

whereas, of course, `sed 's/3.14/pi/g'` would also change `3614`.

The above is a slight oversimplification; it doesn’t account for boundaries. 
Consider this (somewhat contrived) example:

```
$ echo -n 'E' | xxd
0000000: 45                                       E

$ echo -n 'g' | xxd
0000000: 67                                       g

$ echo '$Q Eak!' | xxd
0000000: 2451 2045 616b 210a                      $Q Eak!.

$ echo '$Q Eak!' | xxd -p | sed 's/45/67/g' | xxd -p -r
&q gak!
```

Because `$` (`24`) and `Q` (`51`)
combine to form `2451`,
the `s/45/67/g` command rips it apart from the inside. 
It changes `2451` to `2671`, which is `&q` (`26` + `71`). 
We can prevent that by separating the bytes of data in the search text,
the replacement text and the file with spaces. 
Here’s a stylized solution:

```
encode() {
        xxd -p    -- "$@" | sed 's/../& /g' | tr -d '\n'
}
decode() {
        xxd -p -r -- "$@"
}
left=$( printf '%s' "$search"      | encode)
right=$(printf '%s' "$replacement" | encode)
encode path/to/the/file | sed "s/$left/$right/g" | decode
```

I defined an `encode` function because I used that functionality three times,
and then I defined `decode` for symmetry. 
If you don’t want to define a `decode` function, just change the last line to

```
encode path/to/the/file | sed "s/$left/$right/g" | xxd -p –r
```

Note that the `encode` function triples the size of the data (text)
in the file, and then sends it through `sed` as a single line
— without even having a newline at the end. 
GNU sed seems to be able to handle this;
other versions might not be able to. 
Also, this does not modify the file in place;
you’ll need to write the output to a temporary file
and then copy it over the original file
(or one of the other tricks for doing that).

As an added bonus, this solution handles multi-line search and replace
(in other words, search and replacement strings that contain newline(s)).

Answer (score 3):

Working on an alpine docker container, i wasn't keen to install python / pearl / ruby / python just to do the very simple operation of a find and replace. All these solutions are horribly complex!!

There are two viable solutions to this:

1. Use a different find + replace from elsewhere (e.g. python/pearl/etc)
2. Escape all the regex metacharacters. We can use sed for this purpose.

I cannot do the first in my case as I am working in a minimal docker container.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) solution can be used for the second

In my case i had a known string in my file: `{{replace_me}}` and a user input. Lets call it `$replace_text`.

```
sed -i "s/{{replace_me}}/$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$replace_text")/g" path/to/file
```

How does it work?

We use `sed -i` for an inplace conversion. Here i use the `\` as a delimiter as I am specifically escaping this in my replacement line. This protects against the user putting down `my\string`.

The `$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$replace_text")` bit is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) in a great answer where this solution is derived from. In this case I am using it as a one liner

In answer to OPs initial question, here is a sed one liner that should do the trick:

```
sed -i "s/$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$search_text")/$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<<"$replace_text")/g" path/to/file
```

but i guess he probably no longer cares given that it has been 7 years!

Comment: This is complicated. (1) When I started to read this, I thought “This is only trying to solve the second half of the problem — the replacement string.  That’s not ideal, but a partial answer is better than none.”  But then I saw that your answer was trying to solve the whole problem, and it’s wrong.  If `$initial_text` is `3.14`, then the `printf` outputs `3.14`.  But **`.`** is a special character in regular expressions, so `s/3.14/foo/` will find and replace `3614`, `3q14`, `3%14`, etc. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You say that one can use “anything” as the delimiter for the **```s```** command.  That’s misleading; you can use *any **single character**.*  There are, indeed, times when doing text manipulation that we assume that we can choose a *string* that’s so “obscure” that it will not appear naturally in the data.  But you can’t do that with a single character; the initial\_text and the replace\_text can, between them, contain every valid ASCII character.  So what do you use as the delimiter then? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Gotcha!  It seems like you don’t fully understand how your answer works.  `printf "%q" "my|string"` outputs `my\|string`, and so it will work even if you use `|` as the delimiter!  (4) In your answer, you put the `$(…)` command substitutions outside quotes.  This will cause it to break if initial\_text or replace\_text contains space(s). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) Your fourth paragraph (the third one after the first code block) uses sloppy terminology.  You say ``"$(printf "%q" "$replace_text")"`` converts a regex string to an escaped string.  But replace\_text isn’t a regex — the replacement string in an **`s`** command is a specially formatted string that needs special handling, but it’s not a regex.  Please try to use correct terminology. (6) Your initial example is misleading.  In the context you show, `{` and `}` aren’t special characters and don’t need to be escaped.

Comment: I concede that the "replace" and the python options are simpler, but as stated my solution is for a minimal docker container. There isn't really another solution here for that use case.
Okay onto your points: (1) - valid, my understanding of printf mistook "ready for shell interpretation" as "regex safe" - clearly not the same thing. Will look for a replacement and update the answer (and my own code!). (2/3) fair, people not knowledgeable in sed wouldn't get that i meant any single char. Will update. Your insight is interesting. Any Regexp char works, if we know that others are escaped.

Comment: Cont.. (4) beginner mistake, will update. (5) fair will update wording here, alongside new regex escaping solution. (6) ok i use a different string in my case and i adapted it for this answer, will change to be a little simpler

Comment: Update: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) seems to fit my purpooses - will be swapping out the printf for this and i have a working solution

Answer (score 2):

I pieced together a few other answers and came up with this:

```
function unregex {
   # This is a function because dealing with quotes is a pain.
   # http://stackoverflow.com/a/2705678/120999
   sed -e 's/[]\/()$*.^|[]/\\&/g' <<< "$1"
}
function fsed {
   local find=$(unregex "$1")
   local replace=$(unregex "$2")
   shift 2
   # sed -i is only supported in GNU sed.
   #sed -i "s/$find/$replace/g" "$@"
   perl -p -i -e "s/$find/$replace/g" "$@"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with newlines. Also doesn't help to escape newlines with `\n`. Any solution?

Comment: find and replace need different escaping, see the answer by `VasyaNovikov`. `\n` can be escaped with `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s,\n,\\n,g'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use php's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
php -R 'echo str_replace("\|!£$%&/()=?^\"'\''","replace",$argn),PHP_EOL;'<input.txt >output.txt
```

**Note:** You would still need to escape single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in sh without any script (though putting this "one-liner" into a script would be better) or non-standard external program (I reeeally liked @Nowaker's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/802490/241800) thanks to it's safety against injection, but this old CentOS box I needed this on didn't have ruby!). <sub>as long as `perl` isn't non-standard for you</sub>

Without attempting to *escape* the string (and account for issues with doing it correctly syntactically, knowing all the special characters, et cetera), we can just blanket *encode* all the strings so that nothing has the possibility of being special.

```sh
cat path/to/the/file | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' \
| perl -pe "s/$(printf '%s' 'text' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')(?=(?:.{2})*\$)/$(printf '%s' 'replacement' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')/g" \
| xxd -p -r
```

---

This was just to match the asker's example, other users can obviously replace `'text'` with `"$text"` if using a variable, or `cat path/to/the/file` with `printf '%s' "$input"` if not using a file.

You can even replace the `/g` with `/` to make it replace-once, or otherwise edit the regex outside the `$()` to "escape" only portions of the matcher (say, add a `^` after `s/` to make it match only the start of the **file**).
<sub>If in the above you need ^/$ to match *ends-of-lines* again you'll need unencode those:</sub>

```sh
cat path/to/the/file | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/0a/\n/g'\
| perl -pe "s/^$(printf '%s' 'text' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')(?=(?:.{2})*\$)/$(printf '%s' 'replacement' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')/g" \
| sed 's/\n/0a/g' | xxd -p -r
```

<sub>Which'll replace all lines in the file begining with 'text' to instead start with 'replacement'</sub>

---

Test:

Within `^/.[a]|$0\\{7}!!^/.[a]|$0\\{7}!!^/.[a]|$0\\{7}`, replace literal `^/.[a]|$0\\{7}` with literally `$0\\`

```sh
printf '%s' '^/.[a]|$0\\{7}!!^/.[a]|$0\\{7}!!^/.[a]|$0\\{7}' \
| xxd -p | tr -d '\n' \
| perl -pe "s/$(printf '%s' '^/.[a]|$0\\{7}' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')(?=(?:.{2})*\$)/$(printf '%s' '$0\\' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n')/g" \
| xxd -p -r
```

Output:

```sh
$0\\!!$0\\!!$0\\
```

Comment: (1) This looks *a **LOT*** like [wef’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54059656/3960947#54059658 "How to search & replace arbitrary literal strings in sed and awk (and perl)") to a very similar question.  I’m not accusing you of copying it — it’s certainly possible for people to discover / devise the same solution independently — just advising you that somebody else posted this before you.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) When I first saw this answer, I thought it was brilliant.  A few minutes later, I realized that, like a diamond, it was flawed.  For example, if you try to change `E` to `g` in a file that contains `$Q`, it will change to `&q`.  This is because `E` is `45`, `g` is `67`, and `$Q` is `2451`, so, when you do ```s/45/67/```, you change `2451` to `2671`, which is `&q` (`26` + `71`).  … I have posted an answer that addresses this issue.

Comment: thanks for that @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' not too hard to fix, it'll work now

Answer (score 1):

Node.JS equivalent of @Nowaker:

```
export FNAME='moo.txt'
export FIND='search'
export REPLACE='rpl'
node -e 'fs=require("fs");fs.readFile(process.env.FNAME,"utf8",(err,data)=>{if(err!=null)throw err;fs.writeFile(process.env.FNAME,data.replace(process.env.FIND,process.env.REPLACE),"utf8",e=>{if(e!=null)throw e;});});'
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres one more "almost" working way.

Use vi or vim.

Create a textfile with your substitution in it:

```
:%sno/my search string \\"-:#2;g('.j');\\">/my replacestring=\\"bac)(o:#46;\\">/
:x
```

then execute vi or vim from the commandline:

```
vi -S commandfile.txt path/to/the/file
```

:%sno is the vi command to do search and replace without magic.

/ is my chosen separator.

:x saves and exits vi.

You need to escape backslashes '\' the forwardslash '/' may be replaced with e.g. a questionmark '?' or something else that is not in your search or replace-string, pipe '|' did not work for me tho.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254820/perform-a-non-regex-search-replace-in-vim
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_without_need_to_escape_slash
http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html

Answer (score 1):

## Using a Simple Python Script

Most systems have python ready to go these days. So here's a simple script that'll work for ya:

```
# replace.py
# USAGE: python replace.py bad-word good-word target-file.txt
#
import sys

search_term = sys.argv[1]
replace_term = sys.argv[2]
target_file = sys.argv[3]

with open(target_file, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()

content = content.replace(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

with open(target_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(content)
```

**One Caveat**: This works great if your good/bad words are already in system/environment variables.
Just make sure you use double-quotes to wrap the variables when passing to the script.

For example:

```
python replace.py "$BAD_WORD" "$GOOD_WORD" target-file.txt
```

However, **these will not work**:

```
# This breaks on $ or " characters
BAD_WORD="your-artibrary-string"

# This breaks on ' characters
BAD_WORD='your-artibrary-string'

# This breaks on spaces plus a variety of characters
BAD_WORD=your-artibrary-string
```

## Handling Arbitrary Literal Characters

### 1. Write the Chars to Disk

If I need to provide a arbitrary literal value to a script (skipping any escaping), I generally write it to disk using this method:

```
head -c -1 << 'CRAZY_LONG_EOF_MARKER' | tee /path/to/file > /dev/null
arbitrary-one-line-string
CRAZY_LONG_EOF_MARKER
```

... where:

- We're employing the [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) mechanism to write literal text
- We're using `head` and `tee` to delete the trailing newline that Here Docs create
- We're preventing evalution of variables inside the Here Doc by quoting the EOL marker string

Here's a quick demo with tricky chars:

```
head -c -1 << 'CRAZY_LONG_EOF_MARKER' | tee /path/to/file > /dev/null
1"2<3>4&5'6$7 # 8
CRAZY_LONG_EOF_MARKER
```

### 2. Use Modified Python Script

Here's an updated script that reads from word files:

```
# replace.py
# USAGE: python replace.py bad-word.txt good-word.txt target-file.txt
#
import sys

search_term_file = sys.argv[1]
replace_term_file = sys.argv[2]
target_file = sys.argv[3]

print [search_term_file, replace_term_file, target_file]

with open(search_term_file, 'r') as file:
        search_term = file.read()
with open(replace_term_file, 'r') as file:
        replace_term = file.read()
with open(target_file, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()

print [search_term, replace_term]
content = content.replace(search_term, replace_term)

with open(target_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an `fsed` implementation with `grep` and `dd` ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69479243/10440128))

limitation: the pattern can match only single lines = the pattern cannot contain `\n`

this version will replace only the first match. to replace more matches, remove `-m 1` and loop all matches

```bsh
fixedReplaceFirst(){ # aka fsed (fixed string editor)
  input="$1"
  pattern="$2"
  replace="$3"
  match="$(echo "$input" | grep -b -m 1 -o -E "$pattern")"
  offset1=$(echo "$match" | cut -d: -f1)
  match="$(echo "$match" | cut -d: -f2-)"
  matchLength=${#match}
  offset2=$(expr $offset1 + $matchLength)
  echo "$input" | dd bs=1 status=none count=$offset1
  echo -n "$replace"
  echo "$input" | dd bs=1 status=none skip=$offset2
}

read -d '' input <<EOF
#%replace_me

here,
#%replace_me
is not replaced
EOF

read -d '' replace <<EOF
a=1
b=2
EOF

fixedReplaceFirst "$input" "^#%replace_me$" "$replace"
```

there is [rpl](https://github.com/rrthomas/rpl) (python), but it requires a regular file, so it does not work to replace stdin to stdout

```
$ echo $'[(\n.*' >temp.txt
$ rpl $'[(\n.*' 'yep'
$ cat temp.txt
yep
```

there is [replace](https://replace.richardlloyd.org.uk/) (C, [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/tools/text/replace/default.nix)), but it fails on newlines

```
$ replace-literal '[(.*' 'yep' <<< '[(.*'
yep

$ replace-literal $'[(\n.*' 'yep' <<< $'[(\n.*'
[(
.*
```

Answer (score 1):

just in case I will need this in the future again

```
subject=' http://a\tbc/ef.png?&;wert="3$3*4%5"#eft def '
search='http://a\tbc/ef.png?&;wert="3$3*4%5"#eft'
replace='e&*$%\tf.png'
echo "$subject" | awk -v srch=$(printf "%s" "$search"| sed -e 's/\\/\\\\\\\\/g' -e 's/[?&*.$]/\\\\\0/g' ) -v replc=$(printf "%s" "$replace"| sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g'  -e 's/[?&]/\\\\\0/g'  ) '{gsub(srch, replc, $0); print}' 2> /dev/null
```

srch and replc are escaped in as subshell
not sure if it actually adds value here, but this should get around  mostly all special chars

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the many answers here and not finding a straightforward way to do find + replace with string literals (not regular expressions) with `sed` / `git grep`:

I wrote a small CLI tool to do this:

```bash
go install -v github.com/paralin/git-find-replace@main
cd ./my/git/repo
git find-replace 'SearchString' 'ReplaceString'
```

The [source code](https://github.com/paralin/git-find-replace/blob/main/git-find-replace.go) for the tool is available on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

***Bash can do it!***

```bash
zInput='string .* to .* search'
zMatch='.*'
zResult=''
while :; do
    [[ "$zInput" =~ (.*)("$zMatch")(.*) ]] || break
    zResult="replacement${BASH_REMATCH[3]}$zResult"
    zInput="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
zResult="$zInput$zResult"
echo "$zResult"
```

outputs

```
string replacement to replacement search
```

Quoted strings (no matter how you quote them ('' "" $'')) on the right side of the =~ are not interpreted as regex, but instead taken literally.

Result is built backwards because leftmost .* is greedy.

Comment: Or just `zResult=${zInput//"$zMatch"/"replacement"}`