# Replacing [0-9] with [A-J] not working with sed

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

I am working on a command that replaces all digits 0-9 with their corresponding letters in sed. I know I'm doing something wrong, but sed is not interpreting the replacement regex as anything but a string literal.

The command I am using is `sed -r 's/[0-9]/[A-J]/g' log > ~/output.txt`

It seems pretty straightforward to me, but I have been stuck on it for about an hour. The output I receive just replaces 0-9 with the string "[A-J]"

Answer (score 37):

In substitution, only the *match* (left-hand side) is a regular expression. The *replacement* is more or less just a literal string (with some backslash expansion) – it's **not a regex**.

You want transliteration, not substitution, so replace `s` with `y`:

```
echo 34031445 | sed 'y/0123456789/ABCDEFGHIJ/'
```

sed can't use ranges in `y`, but Perl can:

```
echo 34031445 | perl -pe 'y/0-9/A-J/'
```

Or just use `tr`:

```
echo 34031445 | tr 0-9 A-J
```

Comment: Agreed. `tr` is the easiest and probably the fastest tool for the job.